# Correct dependencies to link to use Google Calendar API

Tags: java, android, google-calendar-api, google-data-api

I downloaded and linked all the jars beginning with `google-...-client` and all the jars  in the dependency folder of the newest google data api for java to my project. However, when I run it, Dalvik gives me this error:

```
[2012-02-12 01:49:33 - P_Timetable_Free] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2012-02-12 01:49:33 - P_Timetable_Free] Note: there were 852 duplicate class definitions.
[2012-02-12 01:49:33 - P_Timetable_Free] Warning: javax.jdo.JDOEnhancer: can't find superclass or interface java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer
[2012-02-12 01:49:33 - P_Timetable_Free] Warning: javax.transaction.TransactionRequiredException: can't find superclass or interface java.rmi.RemoteException
[2012-02-12 01:49:33 - P_Timetable_Free] Warning: javax.jdo.JDOEntityManagerFactory: can't find superclass or interface javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
[2012-02-12 01:49:33 - P_Timetable_Free] Warning: javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: can't find superclass or interface java.rmi.RemoteException
//... and tons more
```

I suspect that there are conflicts in the jars I have linked.

Does anyone know the correct set of jars to link to run so that this error doesn't occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core & Client

- google-api-client-1.6.0-beta.jar
- google-api-client-extensions-1.6.0-beta.jar
- google-api-client-extensions-1.6.0-beta.jar
- google-api-client-extensions-android2-1.6.0-beta.jar
- google-http-client-1.6.0-beta.jar
- google-http-client-extensions-1.6.0-beta.jar
- google-http-client-extensions-android2-1.6.0-beta.jar
- google-http-client-extensions-android3-1.6.0-beta.jar
- google-oauth-client-1.6.0-beta.jar
- google-oauth-client-extensions-1.6.0-beta.jar

Dependencies

- httpclient-4.0.3.jar
- jackson-core-asl-1.9.1.jar
- Guava

Calendar Client
[google-api-services-calendar-v3-1.3.1-beta.jar](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Calendar_API)

Start from this set and add other dependencies as necessary (ClassNotFoundException). It looks like you have JDO jars in classpath that are trying to enhance POJOs. Do you need them? If not, please remove them to keep the binary size in check.